# SQL query command

Tags: sql, sum

I am new to SQL and I need to find a command in order to generate a report regarding a table I have:

```
column1     Tax      Amount   
  350        45        x          
  6500       53        y
  800        25        z
```

I need to calculate x, y and z. I need to do the math:

```
=IF(column1 <= 5000, column1 + tax, column1)
```

In words: You need to calculate x/y/z as the sum of `column1+Tax` with the options:

- if `column1` is smaller or equal to 5000 then `x = column1 + tax;`
- if `column1 > 5000` then x or y or z should have the `column1` value as a result

Can you help me to find the SQL query that calculates x or y or z?

> [image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column1, Tax,
    CASE WHEN column1 <= 5000 THEN column1 + Tax
         ELSE column1
    END AS Amount
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: hi and thanks for the help. I need to calculate the sum Amount column: 
x + y + z 
which i need to write in power shell the script in order to make this query automatic for each month that i need to do the report.
Please support.
Thank you

Comment: I believe I have given you a query which matches what you originally asked.  If you want something different, then show us sample output.

Comment: I don't see how your screen capture changes anything.

Comment: At the first table winnings is calculated from the sum of all Prizes.
I would like to change the calculations of sum of winnings with the conditions of values below and over 5000: if prizes are below 5000 then winning of that ticket (aaaa) is to include prize + tax.
many thanks